I'm currently working on a React Native project and have been using the Metro bundler to serve my application
Android Bundled 2787ms (C:\Users\kuara\OneDrive\Desktop\Map Native\MapApp\node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js)
ERROR  ViewPropTypes will be removed from React Native, along with all other PropTypes. We recommend that you migrate away from PropTypes and switch to a type system like TypeScript. If you need to continue using ViewPropTypes, migrate to the 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types' package.
ERROR  Native part of Mapbox React Native libraries were not registered properly, double check our native installation guides.
ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'StyleURL' of null, js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called., js engine: hermes

i dont have any idea
